# Html sent using the php function called mail() is not display as expected when received

Tags: php, html, email

I have this php script that generates html tables and sends them via mail() function.

here is a sample of the generated html code :

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>Dates</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>05/07</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>06/07</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>07/07</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>08/07</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>09/07</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>10/07</b></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><b>11/07</b></td>
</tr>
<tr">
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">Pointage personnel</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">35</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">38</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">38</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">38</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">38</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; background-color:Tomato;">0</td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; background-color:Tomato;">0</td>
</tr>
...
</tbody></table>
```

Here is the php code for sending the email :

```
/// Sending emails
 $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"; // or utf-8
 $headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'. "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'From: ABC <abc@redacted.com>' . "\r\n";
 $listEmails = [
     "redacted@gmail.com",
     "redacted@outlook.com",
 ];
 foreach ($listEmails as $email){
     mail($email,"# REPORTING  #",nl2br($html),$headers);
 }
```

Here is how the genereted html is displayed on the browser when i use echo (before sending the email) :

[image: how the genereted html is displayed on the browser when i use echo (before sending the email)]

Here is how it is displayed on Outlook or gmail after being sent via mail() function:

[image: how it is displayed on Outlook or gmail after being sent via mail() function]

I tried "inspect element" on gmail side here is the html code that i got :

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:none" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>Dates</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>05/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal" >
            &lt; td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 4px; text-align: center;"&gt;<b>06/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>07/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>08/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>09/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>10/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            <b>11/07</b><u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border:solid black 1.0pt;border-top:none;padding:3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt 3.0pt">
        <p class="MsoNormal">
            Pointage personnel<u></u><u></u>
        </p>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
...
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: It's _probably_ not relevant, but what happens if you don't use `nl2br` on the HTML?

Comment: i removed it but the issue still occurs.

Comment: What's odd is that the problem does not occur in the same table or cell. 
Each time i run the script a random cell or table is a affected.

Comment: I searching more for a solution, i suspect the problem is due to using HTML Shorthand Properties : 
Instead of using ( border: 1px solid black;) i should use ( border-width: 1px ; border-style: solid; border-color: black;)
I'll do some more testing, once i'm sure i'll post this as an answer.

Comment: In your screenshot, it appears there is a white space character between the `<` and `td` character sequences, which may throw off the parsing of the HTML by the client application. However I’m not seeing that same white space in your snippet - can you confirm the code in your snippet matches *exactly* with what you’re actually working with?

Comment: I am certain the white space is absent in the original HTML code, it is added at some point (probably by the client application) at random positions.
After some testing I' am almost certain the issue happens because i was using shorthand properties.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from using **shorthand css properties** while styling the HTML.
In my case i was using :

```
<td style = "border: 1px solid black;"> cellText </td>
```

I should write my inline css like this inst

```
<td style = "border-width: 1px ; border-style: solid; border-color: black;">
   cellText 
</td>
```

I Have made this change in my code and tested it and the issue was gone.